IIS WEB APP MANAGE - CLEAR recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
I am trying to set some App pool configurations using appcmd.exe commands!
I have command to set the periodic recycling like this:
set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='AppPoolName'].recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='19:05:00']" /commit:apphost

It works fine the first time - but when we do redeploy it fails due to the existing periodic recycle value.
How can I first clear all values in periodic recycling scheduler using appcmd.exe ?
Or if someone has solution to skip this command ?

I can reproduce the similar issue when using the same appcmd.exe command to set the periodic recycling.


How can I first clear all values in periodic recycling scheduler using appcmd.exe ?

You can use the following command to remove the existing periodic recycling value : change /+ to /-
set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /-"[name='AppPoolName'].recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='19:08:00']" /commit:apphost

To use the commands in the IIS Web deploy task, you can refer to the following sample:
steps:
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Manage'
  inputs:
    WebsiteName: 'Default Web Site'
    AddBinding: True
    Bindings: '{"bindings":[{"protocol":"http","ipAddress":"All Unassigned","port":"80","hostname":"","sslThumbprint":"","sniFlag":false}]}'
    CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
    AppPoolNameForWebsite: AppPoolName
    ParentWebsiteNameForVD: 'Default Web Site'
    ParentWebsiteNameForApplication: 'Default Web Site'
    AppCmdCommands: |
     set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /-"[name='AppPoolName'].recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='19:08:00']" /commit:apphost
     set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='AppPoolName'].recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='19:08:00']" /commit:apphost

Classic Pipeline:

Result:

UPDATE:
To remove all elements in collection:
clear config  /section:applicationPools  /[name='AppPoolName'].recycling.periodicRestart.schedule


Hi Kevin thanks for the answer - it does work , but is there a way just to clear config if I have more then on value ?  If value that I try to remove does not exist - it will fail on that step.

@J.Memisevic You can try to use the command:  clear config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools  /commit:apphost to clear all values with appcmd.exe

Thanks man - I was able to find solution:
clear config  /section:applicationPools  /[name='AppPoolName'].recycling.periodicRestart.schedule .. I updated the answer with this small part. Thank a lot.
